# Padding-left not working

Tags: css

I'm trying to emulate the code in [Responsive Data Table](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/) to reformat a table where a row is vertical. My difference is that I want only a single row (an edited row) to be vertical and the rest normal.

```css
tr.utr {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

td.utd {
  display: block;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30%;
}

td.utd:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  left: 6px;
  width: 60%;
  padding-right: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

td.utd:nth-of-type(1):before {
  content: "First";
}

td.utd:nth-of-type(2):before {
  content: "Second";
}

td.utd:nth-of-type(3):before {
  content: "Third";
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Query</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=3>Copy of https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>100 Central Ave.</td>
      <td>Listings</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="utr">
      <td class="utd">
        <input type="text" value="123 Main Street" style="width:200px">
      </td>
      <td class="utd"><select>
            <option value="1">Listings</option>
            <option value="2">Solds</option>
          </select></td>
      <td class="utd"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>666 Oceanview Rd.</td>
      <td>Listings</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's my Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ImTalkingCode/k1pcc1nh/4/

In the fiddle, both the content label (eg. First) and the input fields are padded over by the 30% and are not aligned at all like the css-tricks example. Any help?

[Screenshot with the bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzL4j.jpg)

Comment: delete the `padding-left:30%;` to get rid of the left padding?

Comment: I could do that but input fields are not aligned. I want the two elements (content label, and input fields) to look like 2 columns (like in the css-tricks example).

Comment: Not inline. I want the <td> elements to be vertical in the td.utd rows. It comes out vertical but the 2 columns that are displayed: content label and the input elements are not aligned. The jsfiddle shows the issue.

Comment: Do you want it to be something like this https://jsfiddle.net/owfzs7c0/1/ , but the "First" and the "textbox" should be vertical?

Comment: First of all, thank you for taking the time to answer. I want the 2nd row to have the <td> elements vertical instead of the normal horizontal. In the css-tricks example all rows are vertical, and the content ("First") column and the <td> data are perfectly aligned in 2 columns. In my example, it's as though the padding-left: 30% is not working, since this should be doing the alignment.

Comment: I don't think I quite understand what you need, but please check this https://jsfiddle.net/k1pcc1nh/5/ . Resize the windows too, is this what you need?

Comment: Your fiddle is perfect if I wanted all rows to have their <td> elements vertical but I only want a single row (the one that contains the input, select) to be vertical.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153926/discussion-between-ovidiu-unguru-and-imtalkingcode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code from css tricks that you offered, I simply added the classes that we needed.

Resize your screen/browser to see the effect you wanted.

```css
Generic Styling, for Desktops/Laptops 
*/
table { 
  width: 100%; 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}
/* Zebra striping */
tr:nth-of-type(odd) { 
  background: #eee; 
}
th { 
  background: #333; 
  color: white; 
  font-weight: bold; 
}
td, th { 
  padding: 6px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  text-align: left; 
}


@media 
only screen and (max-width: 760px),
(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {

 
 /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
 
 tr.utr { border: 1px solid #ccc;
             display: flex;
             flex-direction: column;}
 
 td.utd { 
  /* Behave  like a "row" */
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30%; 
 }
 
 td.utd:before { 
  /* Now like a table header */
  position: absolute;
  /* Top/left values mimic padding */
  top: 6px;
  left: 6px;
  width: 45%; 
  padding-right: 10px; 
  white-space: nowrap;
 }
 
 /*
 Label the data
 */
 td.utd:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "First"; }
 td.utd:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Second"; }
 td.utd:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Third"; }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Query</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>100 Central Ave.</td>
      <td>Listings</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="utr">
      <td class="utd">
        <input type="text" value="123 Main Street" style="width:100%">
      </td>
      <td class="utd"><select>
        <option value="1">Listings</option>
        <option value="2">Solds</option>
      </select></td>
      <td class="utd"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>666 Oceanview Rd.</td>
      <td>Listings</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you don't want it to be responsive, just delete the `@media` query.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you
https://jsfiddle.net/31rg4ued/.

If you adjust the width of input element based on the padding, you will get the expected output

```css
tr.utr {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
td.utd {
  display: block;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  position: relative;
  
}
td.utd:before {
 
  
}
td.utd:nth-of-type(1):before {
  content: "First";
}
td.utd:nth-of-type(2):before {
  content: "Second";
}
td.utd:nth-of-type(3):before {
  content: "Third";
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Query</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>100 Central Ave.</td>
      <td>Listings</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="utr" style="padding-left:30%">
  
      <td class="utd">
        <input type="text" value="123 Main Street" style="width:calc(100% - 30%)">
      </td>
      <td class="utd"><select>
        <option value="1">Listings</option>
        <option value="2">Solds</option>
      </select></td>
      <td class="utd"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>666 Oceanview Rd.</td>
      <td>Listings</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What is different than his fiddle , though? Seems to be the same thing

Comment: Have you read the question. Actually the link "Screenshot with the bug" is the expected output. The person who edited the question made mistake.

Comment: Thanks. That's very close but the column that contains the input, select, etc. is not left-aligned. The "screenshot bug" shows this.

Comment: In the image also it not aligned. Do you want these elements as left aligned?